# Deleted Default Web Site by mistake on iis8

Tags: asp.net, iis-8

I have deleted Default Web Site Directory on iis 8 accidentally.

Then I want to add a new web site. But OK button is disabled pop-up window.and iis Binding is missing.[image]

Comment: You need to setup the directory for the website you are creating (usually `intepub/wwwroot`).

Comment: How do I perform this operation?

Comment: http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/create-a-web-site (follow the instructions for **USE THE UI**)

Answer (score 1):

I just finished solving this problem myself, it was a really random solution, but it worked...

**

- Open the start menu.
- Type and run Turn Windows Features On or Off.
- Find Internet Internet Information Services, and uncheck it.
- Reboot your pc.
- Repeat steps 1 and 2.
- Recheck Internet Information Services.

**

Basically a built in reconfiguration. Should work after that.